# Fitting pentominoes inside a 10x10 grid

Tags: mathematics, geometry, optimization, polyomino, packing

What is the most number of [pentominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino) that you can fit inside a 10x10 grid, such that they do not overlap or touch each other orthogonally (horizontally or vertically)?

**Bonus:** what is the most number of **distinct** free pentominoes you can fit?

Comment: Bonus asked for $8\times 8$: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115794/how-many-distinct-pentominoes-are-possible-to-place-on-an-8-x-8-board

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bonus:

> The maximum number of distinct free pentominoes is $12$:
>
> ```
> W.YYYY.UUU
> WW.Y...U.U
> .WW.NNN.X.
> T..NN..XXX
> TTT..FF.X.
> T..ZZ.FF.I
> .PP.Z.F..I
> PPP.ZZ.V.I
> ...L...V.I
> LLLL.VVV.I
> ```

I used integer linear programming as follows.  Introduce binary decision variable $x_p$ for each possible placement of a pentomino in the grid.  Let binary decision variable $y_{ij}$ indicate whether cell $(i,j)$ is an orthogonal neighbor of at least one selected pentomino.  Let $P_{ij}$ be the set of pentominoes that contain cell $(i,j)$.  Let $N_p$ be the set of cells that neighbor pentomino $p$.  The original problem is to maximize $\sum_p x_p$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{p\in P_{ij}} x_p + y_{ij} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $(i,j)$} \tag1\label1 \\
x_p &\le y_{ij} &&\text{for all $p$ and $(i,j)\in N_p$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} prevents cell $(i,j)$ from appearing in more than one selected pentomino and from both appearing in one selected pentomino and neighboring a selected pentomino.
Constraint \eqref{2} forces $y_{ij}=1$ for all cells $(i,j)$ that neighbor selected pentomino $p$.

For the bonus problem, let $t_p$ be the type (F,I,L,N,P,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z) of pentomino $p$, and let binary decision variable $z_t$ indicate whether at least one pentomino of type $t$ is selected. The problem is to maximize $\sum_t z_t$ subject to \eqref{1}, \eqref{2}, and
\begin{align}
z_t &\le \sum_{p: t_p = t} x_p &&\text{for all $t$} \tag3\label3
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{3} forces some pentomino of type $t$ to be selected if $z_t=1$.

Comment: That is awesome! Well done. I had a feeling that the bonus is possible, but couldn't find it. Can you share your method?

Comment: Best use of Operations Research I've seen.

Answer (score 6):

As a quick baseline solution:

> 12 pentominoes
>
> ```
> IIIII.NNN.
> .....NN..Z
> VVV.X..ZZZ
> V..XXX.Z..
> V.X.X.F.UU
> .XXX.FFF.U
> L.X..F..UU
> L..FF.WW..
> L.FF.WW.PP
> LL.F.W.PPP
> ```

Bonus:

> 11 distinct pentominoes (Y missing)
>
> ```
> IIIII.NNN.
> .....NN..Z
> VVV.X..ZZZ
> V..XXX.Z..
> V...X.F.UU
> .....FFF.U
> L....F..UU
> L.TTT.WW..
> L..T.WW.PP
> LL.T.W.PPP
> ```

---

(Edit) I also found a nice symmetric solution for the first question:

> 12 pentominoes + an L triomino
>
> ```
> .YYYY.WW.Y
> Y.Y..WW.YY
> YY.X.W.F.Y
> Y.XXX.FF.Y
> Y..X.X.FF.
> .WW.XXX..F
> WW.F.X.FFF
> W.FFF.F.F.
> .Y..F.FF.x
> YYYY.FF.xx
> ```

I wonder what Hexomino's solution is...

Comment: That's a great start!

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Do you have a solution which outdoes this? I can get really close rot13(gjryir cragbzvabrf naq bar grgebzvab) but can't outdo it, yet.

Comment: I cannot outdo this, but my gut feeling is that the bonus can be improved...

Comment: Your first solution is optimal.

Comment: I may ask it as another question

Answer (score 5):

Rob Pratt beat me to it, but I'll post anyway because my computer found a couple of other solutions to the bonus question.

> [image]

I used [my own program](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/polysolver.htm) to solve it. I ran it overnight, and after 15 hours it had only found these two solutions. I'll leave it running, but I don't know how long it takes to do an exhaustive search. By the way, I fixed the orientation of the Y pentomino to filter out rotations/reflections.

**Edit:**
The search finished after 30+ hours, and the only other solutions it found were Rob's solution and two minor variations of it, making a total of 5 distinct solutions.

> [image]

Comment: Now after searching 19 hours it also found Rob's solution, plus a variation where the V and I pentominoes are flipped around.

Comment: Cool. Thx for the link. Let us know how long it takes to finish and how many were found.

Comment: Now there is a fifth solution - a variant of Rob's solution where you first flip I and V around, and then flip I and L.

Comment: @JLee Those 5 solutions are all of them - the two above, and Rob's solution and two minor variants of it. I forgot to note the time the search took, but it must have been thirty-something hours. My program is not very fast, but it makes up for it in versatility.

Comment: scherphius Thx for the update. Interesting

Comment: The right solution in the first spoiler and the rightmost solution in the second spoiler are closely related - they only differ in whether the L and I pieces are placed on top or on bottom.