# Tetromino in a Pentomino Lair

Tags: mathematics, geometry, optimization, polyomino, packing

Inspired by [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116632/fitting-pentominoes-inside-a-10x10-grid):

Can you fit twelve pentominoes (not necessarily distinct) and one tetromino inside a 10 x 10 grid such that they do not overlap or touch each other orthogonally (horizontally or vertically)?

Comment: Nice extension of my puzzle!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Yes, and 12 is the maximum number:
>  [image]

Comment: Excellent find! You can see that it can be made rotationally symmetric by changing the middle pentomino to a tetromino and extending the pattern in the rest of the grid to the bottom right (which was my original solution).